# What/where are the treasure maps that I can find?

Tags: assassins-creed-3-liberation

I was just browsing through some of my statistics for the game, and when you go into **Options** > **Stats** > **Exploration** the first thing listed there is **Treasure Maps Found** and I have a 0% there. When I first saw it I thought of the Smugglers missions in The Bayou which revealed a bunch of treasure chest locations, but I've already completed all of those and this still says 0% next to it.

Where are these treasure maps I can find and what all do they actually reveal to me?